# How to use dbus-next (asyncio) with Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, wsgi, dbus

I have a small embedded Linux box with a WSGI web app deployed with nginx + gunicorn + flask.

I'd like to show on the web interface some internals of the linux box, such as service status (running, stopped, and so on). I'm going to use dbus-next python library to get these infos from systemd.

However dbus-next uses asyncio and I don't know if I can use it in my flask application.